# Python Import Modules

Tags: python-import

I am wondering why someone would like to import only specific classes or functions from a module. In other words:
why should I use the following:

```
from abc.xyz import fgh
from abc.uvw import jkl
from abc.klo import mno
```

if I can also just use:

```
import abc
```

I thought that if I import the abc module I should have access to everything that is inside, or am I wrong?

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that these modules are already written code files for performing specific tasks. Whenever I import a module, the compilers/interpreters take the code from that file and in a way append the code to my code (executable). Now lets say, The abc module is of 15 Kb and I only want to use the function xyz from it, then importing the whole 15kb would just be an overhead for my compiler/interpreter. That is why, a good practice is to import only specific functions/classes so that minimum work needs to be done while compiling or interpreting.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a module like a namespace , so if you import abc , you will be able to use abc and refer to anything under abc with abc.something , but if you only import a specific thing from that namespace , for sure you have access to that specific name only in your code.